# insert a new data into the database and get id along the way

Tags: mysql

What is the correct way to get an id of the new inserted data?

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ? ,?)";

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pstmt.setString(1, aUser.getUsername());
pstmt.setString(2, aUser.getEmail());
pstmt.setString(3, aUser.getPassword());

int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true); 

sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, aUser.getUsername());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while( rs.next() ) {
    aUser.setId( rs.getLong(1));
}
```

I think  my code should work fine because I think that I should make a second request the get the id of new inserted data while the connection still open. However, the more I look at the code, the more I think that I can be done better. The code look kind of weird to me. So I wonder how experienced developers handle this situation in professional strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JDBC, you could add `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to your `prepareStatement` call (or `executeUpdate` if you aren't using a prepared statement).  I.e, `stmt.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)`.  You can then get your resulting keys with `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()`.